# Friend function and method with the same name

Tags: c++, friend

The following classes definitions declare a friend function providing an inline definition for it. I was trying to invoke the friend function from a class method with the same name of the friend function, but in order to make it work I have to access it from the enclosing namespace (which also requires a forward declaration, class `C` below). Why the name lookup works for class `A` and it doesn't work in class `B`? Note that the parameters of `B::swap` are different from those of its friend function.

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct A {
    A(int x) : v{ x } {}
    friend void swap(A& x, A& y) { std::swap(x.v, y.v); }
    void swapm(A& other) { swap(*this, other); }
private:
    int v;
};

struct B {
    B(int x) : v{ x } {}
    friend void swap(B& x, B& y) { std::swap(x.v, y.v); }
    void swap(B& other) { swap(*this, other); } // <-- This doesn't compile
private:
    int v;
};

struct C;
void swap(C& x, C& y);
struct C {
    C(int x) : v{ x } {}
    friend void swap(C& x, C& y) { std::swap(x.v, y.v); }
    void swap(C& other) { ::swap(*this, other); }
private:
    int v;
};

int main()
{
    A a1{ 1 }, a2{ 2 }; swap(a1, a2); a1.swapm(a2);
    B b1{ 3 }, b2{ 4 }; swap(b1, b2); b1.swap(b2);
    C c1{ 5 }, c2{ 6 }; swap(c1, c2); c1.swap(c2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether it's a good idea or not, here's an explanation of why it's failing:

The compiler uses several different phases of processing to figure out what your program says. The reason that class `B` doesn't compile is because the failure that's occurring happens before the `friend` would be noticed. Let me explain:

When the compiler gets to the point where it's trying to figure out what `swap` means, it does a name lookup. It uses specific rules that specify where it should look. This is simplified, but basically it first looks for symbols defined in local scope, then in class scope, and then in enclosing (namespace, etc) scopes. It finds the one defined in class scope, and stops looking. That `swap` does not take those 2 parameters, so it the compilation fails.

The `friend` declaration, which allows the free function to access `B`'s internals, acts as an additional declaration for the `swap` function that you've declared in the global namespace. These declarations would be considered by the compiler if it got to the point in name lookup where it was considering functions in the global namespace. In class `B`, the compiler has already stopped processing before it gets to this stage. (And the `friend` declaration would be necessary in an even later phase, when the compiler is working on compiling a version of the `swap` function that works with `B` objects, and wants to figure out, "in this function called `swap` that can take these 2 parameters; can I access `B`'s internals?")

In class `A`, you're using a different name. The name lookup phase doesn't succeed until it locates your free `swap` function. In class `C`, you've given the name-lookup specific instructions, "hey, when you're looking up `swap`, look in global-namespace scope, and ignore the ones in local- and class-scope that you might find."

(Note: description of name-lookup and `friend` updated after @PeteBecker's comment.)

Comment: [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup)

Comment: Re: "can I access it?" -- no, it's accessible with or without the `friend` declaration -- it's a free function, so it has no access controls. `friend` lets the function itself access non-public members of `B` objects.

Comment: It's easy to get tangled up in name lookup. <g>

Comment: @jwismar Thank you, this clarifies it. The reason why in case `C` I need the forward declaration is that friend function definition is not available outside the enclosing scope, unless a specific declaration is provided, right? It's available only via ADL, which I cannot trigger, having put a `::` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

`inline` `friend`? Why not `static` in this case? And not `friend`? And then create a global one that calls the `static`. For me, this is a bad design more than an actual problem.

The method `swap` should be the one doing the work instead of the `friend` (because no need for a friend anymore):

```
struct C {
    C(int x) : v{ x } {}
    void swap(C& other) { std::swap(this->v, other.v); }
private:
    int v;
};

void swap(C& x, C& y)
{
  x.swap(y);    
}
```